# z-index not working in Chrome, works in FF, IE etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with an image that when clicked shows a larger image with a higher z-index this displays outside the div of the smaller image. In FF, IE, etc it displays correctly but in Chrome it shows the overlayed image but it is hidden within the containing div "Overflow: hidden", (it should show outside the box its wider than the containing box and a higher z-index).

So in essence clicking on the underlying image one column wide loads the bigger wider image 2 columns wide on top and outside the div of the underlying image.

The code below works as I mentioned in IE, FF etc

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="tile bg0 hoverImage0">
                <img src="images/expand-icon.png" class="mouse" alt="Image is clickable" title="Image is clickable">
                <img src="images/Image_Expandible.jpg" alt="W">
            </div>
            <div class="tile imageExpanded overlayImage0" style="visibility:hidden">
                <img src="images/Image_EXPANDED.jpg" alt="W">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 80em;
    min-height: 66em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#list {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: .875em;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
    column-fill: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.item {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.tile {
    border: 2px solid #908094;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.mouse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.hoverImage0 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.overlayImage0 {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 840px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition:all 50ms ease-in-out 50ms;
    background: #000;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.imageExpanded {
    width: 848px;
    height: 633px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 6000;
}
.imageExpanded img {
    height: 630px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 6000;
}
```

The javascript:

```
   jQuery(function ($) {
       $("div.hoverImage0").click(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
           $("div.overlayImage0").stop(true, true).css('visibility', 'visible');
       });
       $("div.hoverImage0").mouseleave(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
           $("div.overlayImage0").stop(true, true).css('visibility', 'hidden');
       });)
   };
```

Comment: I tried that, the important ones are the overlayImage0 being at the top of the stack, and the hoverImage0 being below it, the rest can all be on one layer as the z-index is set to for those all on the same layer

Comment: Whatever I do the overlayImage0 is always contained within the <div class="item"> div tag in Chrome.

Comment: `Overflow: hidden` implies that the content should be clipped regardless of z-index setting.

Comment: Yes, but the image must not overflow the containing div that opens on click. So it is required and works perfectly in FF and IE.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured, that the problem is in **position** property of **.item**

So, if you put the line in comment

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    overflow: visible;
/*  position: relative; */  <-- HERE
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

everything seems to be working fine in Chrome.

Here's the test:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
       $("div.hoverImage0").click(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
           $("div.overlayImage0").stop(true, true).css('visibility', 'visible');
       });
       $("div.hoverImage0").mouseleave(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
           $("div.overlayImage0").stop(true, true).css('visibility', 'hidden');
       });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    max-width: 80em;
    min-height: 66em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#list {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: .875em;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
    column-fill: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.item {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    overflow: visible;
/*  position: relative;*/
    z-index: 1000;
}
.tile {
    border: 2px solid #908094;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.mouse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.hoverImage0 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.overlayImage0 {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 840px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition:all 50ms ease-in-out 50ms;
    background: #000;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 5000;
}
.imageExpanded {
    width: 848px;
    height: 633px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 6000;
}
.imageExpanded img {
    height: 630px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 6000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="tile bg0 hoverImage0">
                <img src="http://skywalker.websight-dev.co.za/images/expand-icon.png" class="mouse" alt="Image is clickable" title="Image is clickable" />
                    <img src="http://skywalker.websight-dev.co.za/images/Image_Expandible.jpg" alt="W" />
            </div>
            <div class="tile imageExpanded overlayImage0" style="visibility:hidden">
                <img src="http://skywalker.websight-dev.co.za/images/Image_EXPANDED.jpg" alt="W" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Of course, it's not the best way to fix it, because it looks like a bug (or some conflict between position, overflow and column-count), so maybe you should rebuild the markup.

Comment: Mmmm I see what you mean, if I comment out the position: relative it actually works, but I lose the position top left of the div in both FF and Chrome, so the image is not anchored top left of the .item div.